# Can I create triggers with Admin SDK in my own backend?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firebase and learning it. With [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) you can create trigger listeners to events that happen in Firestore ([firestore events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)) or Authentication ([auth events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events)). Can I create listeners similarly with the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) of Firestore or Authentication in my own nodejs environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Cloud Functions triggers only work on the Cloud Functions backend, as they depend heavily on Google Cloud infrastructure to work efficiently.  There is no exact equivalent for other environments.  You can certainly use the provided nodejs Firestore SDK to set up a document or query listener, just like web and mobile clients, but it won't behave like a Cloud Functions trigger.

Comment: Thank you very much!